# Enable CloudWatch logs for Beanstalk env from Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch

I am creating a new AWS Beanstalk environment with Terrraform.

AWS Console gives you the ability to turn on CloudWatch logs streaming for Beanstalk environments in the config (see image below), however looking at [the provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elastic_beanstalk_environment)I cannot find terraform currently allowing to do that.

I find this feature quite useful, has anyone stumbled upon this before?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use option settings for Elastic Beanstalk [1]:

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "some_env" {
  name                = "some-env-name"
  application         = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.app.name
  solution_stack_name = "64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v2.0.3 running Go 1.4"

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs"
    name      = "StreamLogs"
    value     = "true"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs"
    name      = "RetentionInDays"
    value     = "7"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs"
    name      = "DeleteOnTerminate"
    value     = "false"
  }

}
```

Note that I have given an example for the `name`, `application` and `solution_stack_name` as you have not provided any code in your question. Additionally, keep in mind that `DeleteOnTerminate` will keep the logs for the `RetentionInDays`.

---

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-cloudwatchlogs